# Flashing an MCU with MicroUSB

Tags: microcontroller, usb

I recently bought [This MCU](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?id=83T7141&Ntt=83T7141) and in another question asked how I could flash it. The response was to use a USB to serial Connector (which I wanted to find on newark.com but could not). I wanted to know if I could solder [This microUSB female connector](http://www.newark.com/molex/47491-0001/micro-usb-type-ab-conn-rcpt-5pos/dp/40P3748) to the io pins of my MCU and be able to flash the MCU to over microUSB from my raspberry pi. Can I?

Comment: Please explain - is it just that microcontroller IC you have, or is there a development board as well? If it is just the IC, you will need some form of programmer, either one with a ZIF socket to insert the IC into, or something you just solder the IC onto.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Its just the MCU.

Comment: +1, full marks for adventurousness! I'm actually intrigued by this exercise, please do let us know how it turns out.

Comment: Your first [link](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?id=83T7141&Ntt=83T7141) seems to be broken (the page says "0 product results").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a USB connector to download code to one of those ARM chips, the flash bootloader uses the UART.

I've used one of these USB to serial adapters:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/180836792643?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649

with Flash Magic to download code to an LPC810 chip via the UART connections. You have to connect a pin to ground when applying power to enable flash downloading, details will be in the data sheet.

Comment: Ok. So is there a tutorial online that I can follow or a document that I can read? And also What do you mean by UART?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to flash microcontroller using USB to Serial Converter using FLASH MAGIC tool. Here is article this might help you: [Flashing MCU over Serial Cable](http://www.binaryupdates.com/flash-magic-to-program-nxp-lpc1768/)

Or

You can use secondary boot loader to flash MCU using Rashpberry Pi over microUSB
[Secondary bootloader video to flash MCU over USB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bdMv6Md2D0)